# How many buns fit in the tray?

Tags: c++

My task is to code a program that let's the user input the weight of the dough, the weight of the bun and the dimensions on the tray. Program shall then print out the weight of the dough that is unused (expressed as an integer in grams), how many of the buns that fit on the baking tray and whether you need more baking trays or not

> You must write a subprogram `calculate_bun_stats` that takes 7 integer parameters (`dough_weight`, `weight_per_bun`, `tray_height`, `tray_width`, `number_of_buns`, `buns_on_tray` and `dough_waste`). The subprogram should not print anything on the screen, but only calculate:
>
> • Total number of buns based on total dough weight (`dough_weight`) and weight per bun (`weight_per_bun`). This result must be "sent back" via the parameter `number_of_buns`.
>
> • How many of the buns (`number_of_buns` above) can be placed on a baking sheet with the dimensions `tray_height` and `tray_width`. This result must be "sent back" via parameter `buns_on_tray`.
>
> • The weight of the dough that remains after the dough is divided into buns as above, stated in grams. This result must be "sent back" via the `dough_waste` parameter.
>
> In the terminal it should look like something like this:
>
> ```
> Enter dough weight: 1000g
> Enter bun weight: 27g
> Enter tray size: 10x10
> 1g dough too much.
> 37 of 37 buns fit on the tray.
> You don't need anymore trays.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Enter dough weight: 1500g
> Enter bun weight: 53g
> Enter tray size: 3x5
> 16g dough too much.
> 15 of 28 buns fit on the tray.
> You need more trays.
> ```

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int number_of_buns (int const dough_weight,
            int const weight_per_bun)
{
  return (dough_weight / weight_per_bun);
}

int buns_on_tray (int const total,
          int const tray_height,
          int const tray_width)
{
  return ((tray_height * tray_width) / number_of_buns);
}

int main ()
{
  int dough_weight {};
  int weight_per_bun {};
  int tray_height {};
  int tray_width {};
  char xchar {};
  total number_of_buns(dough_weight, weight_per_bun);

  cout << "Enter dough weight: ";
  cin >> dough_weight;
  cout << "Enter bun weight: ";
  cin >> weight_per_bun;
  cout << "Enter tray size: ";
  cin >> tray_height >> xchar >> tray_width;

  cout << buns_on_tray(number_of_buns, tray_height, tray_width) << " of " << total;
  cout << " buns fit on the tray." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get errors when I try to use my subprogram as a parameter to another subprogram, and don't know how to get around it.

Can anyone share a legitimate solution, or give tips (without using struct and vectors) to this somewhat simple problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `total number_of_buns(dough_weight, weight_per_bun);`?

Comment: "I get errors" is extremely vague. Please edit your post and add the exact error you receive.

Comment: You probabkly want `total number_of_buns(...` -> `int total = number_of_buns(...`.

Comment: your code and your specification already diverge quite a lot - the spec says to create one function ("subprogram") "calculate_bun_stats", yet you create two functions (buns_on_tray / number_of_buns), which should be (output) parameters of the function according to the spec; so I would recommend first trying to understand the spec of this "somewhat simple problem"...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple statements that are wrong:

- this statement:

  ```
  return ((tray_height * tray_width) / number_of_buns);
  ```

  You are trying to divide an integer by the `number_of_buns()` function itself, rather than the *return value* of that function. You are completely ignoring the `total` parameter that was passed in.
- this statement:

  ```cpp
  total number_of_buns(dough_weight, weight_per_bun);
  ```

  `dough_weight` and `weight_per_bun` haven't been given any values from the user yet, `total` is undefined, and `number_of_buns()` is a function that returns an `int`, which you are ignoring.  You need to move this line *after* the user input, and fix the syntax.
- This expression:

  ```cpp
  buns_on_tray(number_of_buns, tray_height, tray_width)
  ```

  You are trying to pass the `number_of_buns()` function itself to the 1st parameter, which expects an `int` instead.  You need to pass in the *return value* of the `number_of_buns()` function.

The code should look more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int number_of_buns (int const dough_weight,
            int const weight_per_bun)
{
  return (dough_weight / weight_per_bun);
}

int buns_on_tray (int const total,
          int const tray_height,
          int const tray_width)
{
  return ((tray_height * tray_width) / total);
}

int main ()
{
  int dough_weight {};
  int weight_per_bun {};
  int tray_height {};
  int tray_width {};
  char xchar {};

  cout << "Enter dough weight: ";
  cin >> dough_weight;
  cout << "Enter bun weight: ";
  cin >> weight_per_bun;
  cout << "Enter tray size: ";
  cin >> tray_height >> xchar >> tray_width;

  int total = number_of_buns(dough_weight, weight_per_bun);

  cout << buns_on_tray(total, tray_height, tray_width) << " of " << total;
  cout << " buns fit on the tray." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky good catch, fixed